# Problem on $\varepsilon-\delta$ proofs

Tags: limits

Just started learning about $\varepsilon-\delta$ proofs and I need some help. My textbook has this exercise:

prove $\lim(2x^2+3)=5$ as $x$ goes to $1$. Firstly $|2x^2+3-5|=2|x^2-1|=2|x-1||x+1|<\varepsilon$

But then the textbook writes: Without loss of generality we assume $x$ belongs to the neighbourhood of $1$ of radius $1$.

What exactly is going on here? To make my question more specific

Why exactly do we say that $x$ belongs to the neighbourhood of $1$ of radius $1$? Do we simply want to write $x+1$ as a number so the inequality consists only of $x-1$ and the $\delta$? If yes with what criteria did we choose radius $1$?

The proof is finished like this

$|2x^2+3-5|<6|x-1|$

The textbook says: $<$ the expression on the right is $<\varepsilon$ if $|x-1|<\varepsilon/6$ alright we wrote $x+1$ as $3$ and found $\delta$ is $\varepsilon/6$ but then it continues $<$ it will be enough to set $\delta=\min(1,\varepsilon/6)$ to prove the claim. What? I don't get what $\min$ is or what $1$ is. Is $(1,\varepsilon/6)$ supposed to be an interval? Because I don't see it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Limits are about when $x$ are close to $1$.  If $x$ is far away from $1$ we don't care at all.  So as we only care about close values we might as well only look at values where $x$ is within a distance of $1$ of $1$.  We just don't care what happens if $x < 0$ (that's too far away) or what happens if $x  > 2$ (ditto.)

Comment: $\min (x,y) = $ the minimum of $x$ or $y$.  If $x \le y$ then $\min(x,y) = x$.  If $y \le x$ then $\min (x,y) = y$.  So $\min(1, \frac \epsilon 6)$ means whichever value is smaller.  $1$ or $\epsilon 6$.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are dealing with *small* neighbourhoods of $1$ of radius $\delta$, once $\delta$ is small enough ($\delta<1$) these will of course be contained in the neighbourhood of radius $1$. Your thinking of "having only "x+1" is correct. Choosing the radius $1$ is arbitrary. You could also have chosen another radius, like for example $2$.
2. Not the interval, just the minimum between the two values, i.e. either $\epsilon/6$ or $1$.

Answer (score 1):

First... Let's get a feel for what a delta epsilon proof is trying to convince us of.

The idea is.  We can make $2x^2 +3$ get close to $5$ by making $x$ get close to $1$.  The get $2x^2 + 3$ within $100$ of $5$ so that that $-95< 2x^2 + 3 < 105$, we can force that to happen if we make $x$ with say $5$ of $1$ if $-4 < x < 6$ then $0 \le x^2 < 36$ and $0 \le 2x^2 < 72$ and $3 < 2x^2 + < 75$ so we got within $100$.

If we wanted to get close, say we wanted to get $2x^2 + 3$ within $\frac 12$ of $5$ we have to get $x$ much close to $1$.  Say within $.1$.  If $.9 < x < 1.1$ then $.81 < x^2 < 1.21$ and $1.62 < 2x^2 < 2.42$ and $4.52 < 2x^2 + 3 < 5.42$ so that is within $\frac 12$.

And if we wanted to get within one-billionth of $5$ then... well, we're just guessing and shooting blind.  We need to prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can get $2x^2 +3$ within $\epsilon$ of $5$ by taking $x$ within some $\delta$ of $1$.  Our job is to show that such a $\delta$ exist.

So if we want $|2x^2 + 3 - 5|<\epsilon$ what range of $x$ will make that happen?

Well, we want $|2x^2 + 3-5| = 2|x-1||x+1| < \epsilon$.  Well, we don't really now how to compare $|x-1|$ to $|x+1|$ because we might have $x$ being negative $|x -1| > |x+1|$ or we might have $x$ somehow be that $|x+1| > |x-1|$.

But wait.... we are trying to find a small range in which $x$ being close to $1$ forces $2x^2 +3$ to be close to $5$ so we are allowed to force the range to be as small as we want.  So we can force it so that range is within $1$ if it makes it easier for us.

And it does.  If $1-1 < x < 1+1$ then we know then $0 < x < 2$ so $-1 < x-1< 1$ so $|x-1| < 1$ and $0 < x < 2$ so $1 < x + 1 < 3$ so $|x+1| > 1$.  That helps us.  That helps us a lot.  We'd have a lot of things to deal with if we thought "but what if $x < 0$ or $x < -1$ or ..."  We don't have to worry about that because we are going to force $x$ close to $1$.

We could assume $x$ is a lot *closer* to $1$ than that if we wanted to but... we don't need to.

So if $0 < x < 1$ and we want to get $|2x^2 +3 -5| = 2|x-1||x+1| < \epsilon$... Well, we know $|x+1|<3$ so we know that $|2x^2 +3-5| = 2|x-1||x+1| < 2|x-1|3 = 6|x-1|$

So if we can get *BOTH* $|x-1| < \frac {\epsilon} 6$ *AND* that $|x-1| < 1$ we would be done.  Because $|x-1|< \frac {\epsilon} 6$ we have that $6|x-1| < \epsilon$.  ANd because $|x-1| < 2$ we have $|x+1| < 3$.  So $|2x^2 +3 -5| = 2|x-1||x+1| < 6|x-1| < \epsilon$.

So how can we force $x$ to be both within $1$ of $1$ and to *also* be within $\frac \epsilon 6$ of $1$?  Well, by letting $\delta$ be the smaller of either $1$ or of $\frac \epsilon 6$.

$\min (a, b)$ means the smaller number of $a$ or $b$.  $\min(\frac 12, \frac 34) = \frac 12$ because $\frac 12 < \frac 34$.  And $\min(a,b)$ can be $a$ if $a < b$.  Or $\min(a,b)$ could be $b$ if $b< a$.   And if $a = b$ then it is $\min(a,b) = a = b$.  We use the$\min$ function to select the smaller value when we don't know which is smaler.

So if $1 < \frac \epsilon 6$ we let $\delta = 1$.  And if $\frac \epsilon 6 \le 1$ we let $\delta = \frac \epsilon  6$.  In other words, we let $\delta = \min (1, \frac \epsilon  6)$.  That way we know $\delta <\le 1$ and $\delta \le \frac \epsilon 6$.

So $|x-1|< \delta$ means $|x-1|< 1$ so $|x+1| < 3$ and $2|x-1||x+1|< 6|x-1|$.   And $|x-1| < \delta$ means $|x-1| < \frac \epsilon  6$ so  $|(2x^2 + 3)-5| = 2|x-1||x+1|< 6|x-1| < 6*\frac \epsilon 6= \epsilon$.

And that's it.  We can force $2x^2 +3$ to be within $\epsilon$ of $5$ by forcing $x$ to be within the minimum of $1$ or $\frac \epsilon 6$ of $1$.

Comment: Thank you.Amazing answer,much appreciated.A couple questions though. 1) We say that x has radius 1 so x+1  is   1<x< 3, but why do we say that x+1 is 3 and not 1 for example why do we take the upper bound? Generally what confuses me about epsilon delta proofs is the reason the manipulations are done in the way they are done. The motivation isnt entirely clear.

Comment: We *don't* say $x + 1 = 3$. We say "we assume x belongs to the neighbourhood of 1 of radius 1" means "$|x-1|<1$ means $1-1<x<1+1$ means $0< x< 2$ means $1< x+1< 3$. In this case $1<x+1$ is utterly useless to us. So is $x< 2$. The two things that are important to us are 1) $0<x$ (because we don't want to deal with changes of signs or absolute values) and 2) $x+1< 3$ (so we force $2|x+1||x-1|<\epsilon$ by noting $2|x+1||x-1|<6|x-1|$ and forcing $|x-1|<\frac\epsilon6$).  We manipulate them to get what we want. And what we want is to force them to be *smaller* than a maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

Given $\epsilon > 0$ we want to find $\delta > 0$ such that $|(2x^2+3)-5|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x - 1| < \delta$.

Note that if one $\delta$ works, then every smaller $\delta$ also works. Therefore we can always require $\delta$ to be less than for example $1$. This is done to make the rest of the calculations easier. This is what the textbook does when it reads "Without loss of generality we assume $x$ belongs to the neighbourhood of $1$ of radius $1$."

With "set $\delta=\min(1,\epsilon/6)$" is meant that we set $\delta$ to the smaller (minimum) of $1$ and $\epsilon/6$. The $1$ comes from having taken $\delta$ to be smaller than $1$. The $\epsilon/6$ comes from the rest of calculations.